# Swift iOS: Closure will not run in background when Remote Notification received

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, gps, closures

I am writing an iOS app that requires the device's GPS loction to be updated when a push notification is received.

I use a closure to get the current GPS location. This code runs perfectly when the app is in the foreground (Both "New remote notification" and "Got location" is printed to console), but when the app is in the background, only "New remote notification" (and no location error) is printed to console. As a result I don't have the GPS location of the device at this point, which is very important for my app's functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

I have in my Info.plist file for 'Required background modes';

```
 App registers for location updates
 App downloads content from the network
 App downloads content in response to push notifications
```

My app also has access to location at all times, including the background (successfully tested at other points in the code): NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is in the Info.plist file

In my AppDelegate file:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary!) {

    println("New remote notification")
    var notification:NSDictionary = userInfo as NSDictionary

    var loc: LocationManager?
    loc = LocationManager()


    loc!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in

        // fetch location or an error
        if let myloc = location {

            var lat = myloc.coordinate.latitude as Double
            var lon = myloc.coordinate.longitude as Double

            println("Got location")

        } else if let err = error {

            println(err.localizedDescription)

        }
        loc = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't that be s problem, that locationmanager is not a property, it's just created in a method?

Comment: How do you mean, Daniel?

Comment: I mean that you should try to declare "loc" in the class, not in the application:did received... Method

Comment: Inside the LocationManager class?

Comment: No, inside the app delegate

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I've implemented both of your suggestions and it now works, though it did require both to work - I tested to see if it was one or the other, but if I removed either of them it wouldn't work again.

Comment: Actually, after more testing, it was specifically Rob's suggestion that fixed the problem - but thank you Daniel for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If app is not in foreground, make sure to ask for a little time to complete the request with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and then call `endBackgroundTask` when done.

For more information, see the *Executing Finite Length Tasks* in the [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) chapter of the *App Programming Guide for iOS.*