# iOS Background task will finish while in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, background

If I use this method to run a task, but keep app in foreground, will expirationHandler be called while app is in foreground?

I use this for starting location service everytime I enter background, but sometimes user enters background and immediately returns to app, will this call **expirationHandler?**

```
func beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler handler: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier
```

Comment: Could you please make it a more clear? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks, I updated description

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, we might need to see the implementation of the method  to judge, that depends on where are you calling `handler`. Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code, there is no guarantee that closure code should run the background or the foreground, it depends on what are you calling it.
[This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011364/swift-ios-closure-will-not-run-in-background-when-remote-notification-received) might be helpful to your case...

Comment: Case is: 1. Go to the background with reported background task. 2. Go back immediately to foreground, but there is still created and active background task. QUESTION: Will it call expiration handler when staying in foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> A handler to be called shortly before the app’s remaining background time reaches 0. Use this handler to clean up and mark the end of the background task. Failure to end the task explicitly will result in the termination of the app. The system calls the handler synchronously on the main thread, blocking the app’s suspension momentarily.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpiratio

It seems that expiration handler is not called in the foreground mode. After very long waiting I went into background mode and then after ~170 seconds expiration handlers were called for all reported previously background tasks.